# How to take derivative of integral of square matrix function

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations, matrix-calculus

I have a function as following

$$F=\int |A^TG(x)-B^TJ(x)|^2 H(x)\,dx+ \int |A^TG(x)-C^TJ(x)|^2 (1-H(x)) \, dx+\lambda_1 A^2+\lambda_2 B^2+\lambda_2 C^2$$

where 
$A^T$ is transpose of vector $A$. $A$ is a column vector such as
$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        a_2 \\
        ... \\
        a_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$; 
$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        b_1 \\
        b_2 \\
        ... \\
        b_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$;
$C=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        c_1 \\
        c_2 \\
        ... \\
        c_n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$; $A^TG(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} a_i G_i $

$G=[G_1...G_i..G_n],J=[J_1...J_i..J_n]$, in which $G_i$ is matrix $n\times n$ and $H(x)$ is [Heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) smoothing function. Note that  given $G,J,H$

I want to find the coefficients of $A,B$ and $C$ subject to $\min F$. Hence, we have equation.

$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial A}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial B}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial C}=0$$
**However, How to find the derivative of these above function?**

$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial A}=?$$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial B}=?$$
$$\frac {\partial F}{\partial C}=?$$

Comment: Try not to use $\times$ to denote regular multiplication. It's a habit that takes a while to shake off but all it does is clutter your equation and make it harder to read.

Comment: Can you help me Cameron Williams

Comment: I cannot. I'm not at all familiar with matrix calculus. Hopefully someone else can help you.